# Can upload image from ImagePicker.openPicker but not ImagePicker.openCamera, react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, axios

I'm currently developing an app in react native.

In the app, a user has a profile image and can update it by
either choosing one from gallery or taking a new one with the camera.

The library used for this is 'react-native-image-crop-picker'.

To choose an image ImagePicker.openPicker is used.
To take a new picture ImagePicker.openCamera is used.

After updating his/her profile image it is also updated to a aws server.

This is the code for that:

```
static uploadFile = async (filePath: string, idToken: string): Promise<AxiosResponse> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

      console.log("filepath: " + filePath);

      // when taking: filepath: /data/user/0/com.myapp/files/1685872451229.jpg
      // when picking: filepath: /data/user/0/com.myapp/files/1685872572898.jpg

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', {
        name: 'profileImage',
        uri: 'file://' + filePath,
        type: 'image/jpg'
      });

      try {
        const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}`, formData, {
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            Authorization: idToken
          }
        });
        resolve(response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
      }
    })
  }
```

When a new profile image is chosen or taken I use react-native-fs 'moveFile'
to update the image in local storage, after the previous has been deleted.

My problem is this:

Whenever I upload an image chosen from Gallery it works just fine, but when uploading a taken picture it times out after a few seconds with:

[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 504]

Are the images in a different format or what might cause this error for Axios?

WHAT I HAVE ALREADY TRIED:

I have tried to set the image quality to a lower percentage, hoping it would solve the problem if the taken picture was "too large".

I have tried the option forceJpg: true for Imagepicker.openCamera.